# Where can I find lots of worked examples of proof by induction?

Tags: reference-request, induction

This may not be an appropriate question. If so I apologise.

I struggle largely with proofs by induction. Can someone please point me toward some learning materials (text-books would be ideal) where induction is explained and there are also a significant number of examples for me to follow?

Comment: If you happen to read a little German, there is a _huge_ collection of exercises and solutions here: http://www.emath.de/Referate/induktion-aufgaben-loesungen.pdf For most exercises you maybe won't even need to read the words.

Comment: Maybe try high school book that teaches induction, I'm sure that such a book will contain even a $100$ problems

Comment: http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/MISS.pdf for series ans equenzes and http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/indprobs.pdf for different types

Comment: You can find plenty of examples on this site...  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/induction

Comment: @belgi I know you meant well, but your answer is not actually useful. It is just restating what OP asked for, and does not add any new information.

Comment: You can also take a look at books with problems from mathematical olympiads for non-trivial problems.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This book was recommended by some of my college professors, and there is an entire chapter on proof by induction:

[How to Prove It by Daniel Velleman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521446635)

Velleman's book goes over many strategies of proof, induction being only one of them. I found another book which focuses exclusively on mathematical induction - as such, the review base is probably not as large, and I haven't heard about it before I searched for it, but it does have a few positive reviews on Amazon:

[Handbook of Mathematical Induction by David Gunderson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420093649)

I should add the disclaimer, however, that I have not personally read either of these books, so YMMV.

Comment: I would like to add that I have gone through Velleman's book (and exercises at the end of the chapter), and currently in the induction chapter. I want to say that his book is amazing. I think it has given me tons of tools. However, my perspective is that it focuses more on proofs related  to sets. I am struggling with the exercises in the induction section, particularly strong induction. So that's why I'm here looking for more resources on this proof technique.